# Using Rust empty type as a generic bound

Tags: generics, rust

How do I constraint a Rust generic type to an empty type? I need to create a type with optional value, so that if the generic type is `()`, it does not use any memory. Here's a simple example - `Data` could be a `i32, ()` (4 bytes) or it could be `i32, i32` (8 bytes). There is an `add()` for both cases.  I get this error (which makes sense, but not sure how to avoid it). I need to handle all valid numeric types.

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `std::ops::Add` for type `Data<(), ()>`
...
note: upstream crates may add a new impl of trait `num_traits::Num` for type `()` in future versions
```

```rust
use num_traits::Num;

trait MyNumericType: Num {}
impl<T: Num> MyNumericType for T {}

struct Data<T1: MyNumericType, T2> {
    a: T1,
    b: T2,
}

impl<T: MyNumericType> Add for Data<T, ()> {
    type Output = Self;

    fn add(self, other: Self) -> Self {
        Self {
            a: self.a + other.a,
            b: (),
        }
    }
}

impl<T: MyNumericType> Add for Data<T, T> {
    type Output = Self;

    fn add(self, other: Self) -> Self {
        Self {
            a: self.a + other.a,
            b: self.b + other.b,
        }
    }
}


impl<T1: MyNumericType,T2> Data<T1, T2>  {
    fn new(a: T1, b: T2) -> Self {
        Self { a, b }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let r1 = Data::new(1, 2) + Data::new(3, 4);
    let r2 = Data::new(1, ()) + Data::new(2, ());
}
```

Comment: One comment that I have for rust under this example is why this line is needed what does it tell rust compiler more than its line above:
impl<T: Num> MyNumericType for T {}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you don't control the `()` type, so someone could, completely unknown to you and with no malicious intent, write an `impl` that breaks your code. Rust forbids this kind of action at a distance.

Fortunately, `()` is a really simple type. So we can just make our own.

```
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
struct MyUnit;
```

`MyUnit` is basically identical to `()` except that it's in *your* crate, not Rust's stdlib and not somebody else's crate. If someone comes along and writes an `impl` for `MyUnit`, then they must already have your crate as a dependency and thus are aware of the risks. Then just write your `impl`s in terms of `Data<T, MyUnit>` instead of `Data<T, ()>`. It's still a zero-sized type and thus is subject to all of the same optimizations as `()`.

Comment: thanks, that's exactly what i was missing!!!